How to swap in base chain (Eth Layer2)
Hello Stack Overflow Community,
I am working on swapping tokens in a base layer2 network using Uniswap V3 and ethers.js. I have successfully approved the transaction using the approve function, but when I try to execute the swap using exactInputSingle, I encounter a "Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [execution reverted]" error.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
import { getPoolImmutables, getPoolState } from './utils';
const { ethers } = require('ethers');
const { abi: IUniswapV3PoolABI } = require('@uniswap/v3-core/artifacts/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Pool.sol/IUniswapV3Pool.json');
const SwapRouterABI = require('./routerabi.json');
const ERC20ABI = require('./abi.json');

const QUICKNODE_HTTP_ENDPOINT = 'https://sepolia.base.org';
const WALLET_ADDRESS = '';
const WALLET_SECRET = '';

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(QUICKNODE_HTTP_ENDPOINT);
const poolAddress = '0x7516D071921973fDFf29C071f42d21C227CF5740'; 
const swapRouterAddress = '0x050E797f3625EC8785265e1d9BDd4799b97528A1';

async function main() {
  const poolContract = new ethers.Contract(poolAddress, IUniswapV3PoolABI, provider);
  const immutables = await getPoolImmutables(poolContract);
  const state = await getPoolState(poolContract);

  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(WALLET_SECRET);
  const connectedWallet = wallet.connect(provider);

  const swapRouterContract = new ethers.Contract(swapRouterAddress, SwapRouterABI, provider);
  const inputAmount = 0.09;
  const amountIn = ethers.utils.parseUnits(inputAmount.toString(), 18);
  const approvalAmount = (amountIn * 10).toString();
  const tokenContract0 = new ethers.Contract(immutables.token1, ERC20ABI, provider);

  const approvalResponse = await tokenContract0
    .connect(connectedWallet)
    .approve(swapRouterAddress, approvalAmount);

  const params = {
    tokenIn: immutables.token1,
    tokenOut: immutables.token0,
    fee: immutables.fee,
    recipient: WALLET_ADDRESS,
    deadline: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 10,
    amountIn: '0x013fbe85edc90000',
    amountOutMinimum: 0,
    sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0,
    nounce: await connectedWallet.getTransactionCount(),
  };

  const transaction = swapRouterContract
    .connect(connectedWallet)
    .exactInputSingle(params, {
      gasLimit: ethers.utils.hexlify(1000000),
      gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits('10', 'gwei'),
    })
    .then((transaction: any) => {
      console.log(transaction);
    });
}

main();


I suspect that I might need to use the execute function, but I'm not sure how to do that or if that's the correct approach.
Any guidance on how to properly execute a swap in a Uniswap V3 pool on a base layer2 network using ethers.js would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

this is params structure
struct ExactInputSingleParams {
        address tokenIn;
        address tokenOut;
        uint24 fee;
        address recipient;
        uint256 deadline;
        uint256 amountIn;
        uint256 amountOutMinimum;
        uint160 sqrtPriceLimitX96;
    }

there is no nonce (you typed nounce).
Also amountIn type us uint256. you already correctly defined
  const amountIn = ethers.utils.parseUnits(inputAmount.toString(), 18);

but in function call you are passing
amountIn: '0x013fbe85edc90000',

it should be
  amountIn: amountIn


Hi
Thanks for your answer
I still have the same issue please check this transaction :
https://sepolia.basescan.org/tx/0x40d19f78e9089f40f7ec204c187439cf3327d1b3a7d20d0f2fc5e23714ba1c5d

Can you check each variable in params to make sure they are valid values, not undefined

Everything looks good to me
{
tokenIn: '0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000006',
tokenOut: '0x355425B645A7fe616e9F91B2b115Bf37F090d2F9',
fee: 10000,
recipient: '0x1991aC5419991ebd2c11783DB5087644B125c912',
deadline: 1712773393,
amountIn: BigNumber { _hex: '0x013fbe85edc90000', _isBigNumber: true },
amountOutMinimum: 0,
sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0,
nounce: 70
}

try with a different rpc node

please check my question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78324700/warning-error-encountered-during-contract-execution-execution-reverted-base

have you resolved the issue in this question?

no it did not sadly

Can you double check if you are using correct contract address for the netwrok

I'm using this :0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad
Also check my question for more informations
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78324700/warning-error-encountered-during-contract-execution-execution-reverted-base

if you check here https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/reference/deployments/ethereum-deployments   swap router contract address for sepolia is 0x3bFA4769FB09eefC5a80d6E87c3B9C650f7Ae48E
